# Is there a better way of implementing this control structure?

Tags: lua

I have the following control structure that I would like to improve:

```
if(number >= 100)    then doSetInc(id, 8, 20)
elseif(number >= 91) then doSetInc(id, 8, 30)
elseif(number >= 81) then doSetInc(id, 8, 50)
elseif(number >= 7)  then doSetInc(id, 8, 70)
elseif(number >= 1)  then doSetInc(id, 8, 100)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Kinda hard to know what you mean with better since you don't specify in what regard.

In regards to cleaner code:

- FunctionName doSetInc is a bit weird, what does it do?
- You are sending in 3 variables into the function, it's common practice to use as few as possible (rarely more than 2, 0 or 1 prefered).
- You are always sending in "id" and "8" into the function, thus this function might not need those attributes and could be set in another way.

Other than that, since I find no easy mathematical similarities between these checks and what to do, I would say no, you can't improve it given this small piece of code and no other context.

Answer (score 4):

1.
What does 'doSetInc' do? Its not a descriptive name.
 - Where does that 8 come from?
 - Where does that 20 come from?

Bad code good code: http://commadot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wtf.png


2.
You have a set of ranges and for each a specific value is to be derived. Depending on how many integers there are to be evaluated, you might want to make a hash containing what each integer turns into.

It would look something like this:

> derived_id{1}->20
>   derived_id{2}->20
>   ...
>   derived_id{64}->70
>   ...

At that you can replace the entire block with a single line.

```
doSetInc(id, 8, derived_id{number})
```

And if you would improve the readability like I suggested above, it would become a single easily readable line.

Be careful though, at this point people may start to feel like you haven't really done anything.

Answer (score 3):

## 1)

To simplify the if else conditions, use `<` instead of `>=`.
Note: This only works correctly if `number` isn't a decimal. Be sure to [round](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleRound).

Old Code:

```
if(number >= 100)    then doSetInc(id, 8, 20)
elseif(number >= 91) then doSetInc(id, 8, 30)
elseif(number >= 81) then doSetInc(id, 8, 50)
elseif(number >= 7)  then doSetInc(id, 8, 70)
elseif(number >= 1)  then doSetInc(id, 8, 100)
end
```

New Code:

```
if( 99 < number )    then doSetInc(id, 8, 20)
elseif(90 < number ) then doSetInc(id, 8, 30)
elseif(80 < number ) then doSetInc(id, 8, 50)
elseif( 6 < number )  then doSetInc(id, 8, 70)
elseif( 0 < number )  then doSetInc(id, 8, 100)
end
```

## 2)

Create a function that retrieves the value of the third parameter, since that's the only thing that changes for the `doSetInc` calls.

## 3)

Rename `doSetInc` to `setInc`.

## 4)

Declare variables as `local`, unless `global` is required.

### Final Code

```
-- core function
local getGrade = function(x)
    local val       
    if ( 99 < number ) then val = 20
    elseif (90 < number ) then val = 30
    elseif (80 < number ) then val = 50
    elseif ( 6 < number ) then val = 70
    elseif ( 0 < number ) then val = 100
    return val;
end 

setInc(id, 8, getGrade( number ) )
```

Use case:

```
local number = 10
local id = "283"
local setInc = function(a,b,c) 
    print( "setInc("..a..", " .. b .. ", " .. c .. ")" )
end

setInc(id, 8, getGrade( number ) )
```